# What term is being referred to with "reflected-sound-of-underground-spirits"?

Tags: discworld, language-explanation

In *The Colour of Magic*, on page 46 of my copy, Twoflower says this word:

> “*Reflected-sound-of-underground-spirits?*”

What term is being referred to above?

It seems to be like “*in-sewer-ants-policy*”, i.e. a term that they don’t have a word for in the language (“insurance policy”), but I can’t figure out what it’d be.

I asked two people who couldn’t figure it out, either.

Comment: I can't even figure out what you're saying, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Maybe provide a bit more context for this?

Comment: @JMac - Additional context isn't really needed when you've read the book.

Comment: @Valorum I had read this part of the book and couldn't remember what it was referring to without seeing the answers.  It seems strange to me. Does Twoflowers actually say "Reflected-sound-of-underground-spirits?" (doesn't seem right) or was that something Rincewind was thinking after Twoflowers tries to explain to him what he does?

Comment: @JMac - Rincewind always transliterates Twoflower's speech into Morporkian. Twoflower is saying "echo-gnomics"

Comment: @Valorum Yes, Rincewind is translating; but without context it appears as though that is what Twoflowers said.  Like for example, _why_ did Twoflowers/Rincewind say "Reflected-sound-of-underground-spirits?" in this part of the book.  Surely he didn't just randomly decide to say it, and any context would make it far easier to understand (even for someone who has read the book, but forgot details, for example).

Comment: I recall this one being easier to work backwards. That is, deduce from the context that "economic" may be the word and only *then* get the joke.

Comment: Am I the only one here who says ***EE***conomics instead of ***EH***conomics?

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes. That's weird.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you are in line with [62% of British speakers](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/magazinemonitor/2009/08/how_to_say_economics.shtml), fwiw

Comment: You already have the answer, but I'll note that the Annotated Pratchett File answers this as well: https://www.lspace.org/books/apf/the-colour-of-magic.html#p44 . I recommend reading the notes there, because they will usually mention something that you haven't noticed to any Pratchett book.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

**The word is "echo-gnomics"** ("economics")

An echo is a reflected sound; gnomes live underground.

Etymologically, "gnomes" [mythology] are described as "a legendary race of human-like beings, usually imagined as short and possibly bearded males, who inhabit the inner parts of the earth and act as guardians of mines, mineral treasure, etc." (Source: [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gnome))

Apparently I've played too much D&D where gnomes aren't specifically tied to the underground.

Comment: And here I thought gnomes dwelt in gardens!

Comment: Those are gnomish felons, @ruakh. Gardens are the penal colonies of the gnome race, much like Australia was for Britain at one point. The bright clothing is both a punishment and a guard against escape.

Comment: In D&D, gnomes have night vision and live in burrows, so they are pretty tied to underground. Are you mistaking them for halflings?

Answer (score 78):

Rincewind tries his hand at a better translation later in the book (emphasis added):

> Bloody hell, he thought. He’s alive! Me too. Who’d have thought it? Perhaps there is something in this reflected-sound-of-underground-spirits? It was a cumbersome phrase. Rincewind tried to get his tongue around the thick syllables that were the word in Twoflower’s own language.
>   “Ecolirix?” he tried. “Ecro-gnothics? **Echo-gnomics?”**
>   That would do. That sounded about right.

As with 'insurance', the concept of 'economics' (a reflected sound is an echo, underground spirits are gnomes) is largely unheard of in that part of the disc. Rincewind describes it as *'financial* wizardry' (emphasis added):

> “Well, my point is, you see, that gold also has its sort of magical field. **Sort of financial wizardry. Echo-gnomics.”** Rincewind giggled.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that _echo-gnomics_ would be pronounced _economics_, something that wouldn't be immediately obvious to people fortunate enough to have been raised speaking languages with rational spelling.

Comment: While a fair point, in my accent at least, _echo-gnomics_ and _economics_ sound quite different!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - I really can't be held accountable for the way that you colonials butcher the English language

Comment: The two have distinct "o" sounds (gnome having a long o). Do people in the UK really pronounce *gnome* as "nom"? It hasn't been my experience.

Comment: @Glen_b - "Gnome" (in RP) would be 'nome' (rhymes with 'home'). "Gnom" (**as in [gnomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomon)**) would usually be 'nom' (rhymes with 'Tom').

Comment: Ah, I finally get it, you're saying the pronunciation of the "o" shifts when it becomes "-gnomics".

Comment: Sure, but the main point, and what I expect would me most confusing to a non-native speaker, is that the _g_ in _gnome_ and, by extension, _echo-gnomics_ is silent. If you come from a language with a spelling system that isn't insane, you would think that the _g_ would be the same sound as you get in _gone_.

Comment: surely it's gnome to rhyme with scone?